# Multiple binary classifiers combining

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a multi layer perceptron classifier, and I have a data set of 1000 sample. There are 6 features and 5 possible different labels

Based on my understanding for OneVsAll, we create a binary classifier per label and train the classifier with the training data.
However, I don't understand how we can combine the results of the 5 binary classifiers. Also, what if the data was noisy and 2 binary classifiers predicted that the test sample was positive? and what we do if all labels binary classifiers predicted that a sample is a negative sample, then how do we label it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output layer, each unit should be returning a value of `h` where `0 < h < 1`. Usually, in a binary classifier, you would choose a threshold value, say `0.5` where you decide whether your output is a positive or negative result. In the case of 1vsAll, you choose the label for the output units with the highest value of `h` as your predicted label.